# How to query using ST_GeometryFromText

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql

I am trying to make a query using `ST_GeometryFromText`.
When I run the code I recive the error posted below

`fieldGeometry` is an object in WKT format

How can I make this query correctly?

Code:

```
def executeWithFetchallST_GeometryFromText(self, cursor, fieldGeometry):
cursor.execute("SELECT ST_GeometryFromText(ST_SetSRID({fieldGeometry},4326));".format(fieldGeometry=fieldGeometry))        
return cursor.fetchall()
```

Error:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ST_GeometryFromText(ST_SetSRID({fieldGeometry},4326));".format(fieldGeometry=fieldGeometry))
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »51.1142127990963«
LINE 1: ...tryFromText(ST_SetSRID(POLYGON ((6.73622172276192 51.1142127...
```

Comment: Change the order and use SetSRID once you have a geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```py
def executeWithFetchallST_GeometryFromText(self, cursor, fieldGeometry):
    cursor.execute("SELECT ST_GeometryFromText(ST_SetSRID({fieldGeometry},4326));".format(fieldGeometry=fieldGeometry))        
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

do

```py
def executeWithFetchallST_GeometryFromText(self, cursor, fieldGeometry):
    cursor.execute("SELECT ST_GeometryFromText('{fieldGeometry}', 4326);".format(fieldGeometry=fieldGeometry))        
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

`ST_GeometryFromText` expects a string with wrapping single quotes around and you can directly assign an SRID in `ST_GeometryFromText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the srid while constructing the geometry (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryFromText.html).

```
SELECT ST_GeometryFromText({fieldGeometry},4326)
```